# Add image comment to excel cell

Tags: c#, excel-2010, office-interop, excel-interop

What is the best way to insert an image comment to a cell in excel using C#?

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

So far I've done

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.Sheets[1];

        var commnetImage = sheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"d:\download.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            0, 0, 100, 200);

        var gg = sheet.Cells.Range["E5"];
        gg.ClearComments();
        gg.AddComment(commnetImage);
        wb.Save();

        excel.Quit();
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the Epplus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for an alternative to using Interops? Interops are generally very slow and untrustworthy. I would suggest having a look at that before continuing  with your project. It is a very simple to use library. I have written some example code to get started a view years ago. Have a look at [My blog](http://www.jasonsmith.co.za/2011/03/readingwriting-xlsx-files.html)

Comment: Jus looking at it now, I see the add comment to cell example, does it support images??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank guys,
Found solution at

[Any open source / free library for handling Excel (both *.xls and *.xlsx) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990871/any-open-source-free-library-for-handling-excel-both-xls-and-xlsx-files)

Didn't manage to find it yesterday, it is using this great open source project http://spreadsheetlight.com/